# K-medoid clustering in python

Tags: clustering, python, algorithms

How do I implement k-medoid clustering algorithms like PAM and CLARA in python 2.7?  I am currently using Anaconda, and working with ipython 2.7. I have tried scipy.clusters but they don't seem to have the above algorithms. Please help

Comment: This seems to be more a computing question rather than a statistics one and therefore would be better suited for Stack Overflow

Comment: I wouldn't agree. Asking for a data analytic algorithm and/or theory is in tune with our site. Particular programming questions should go to SO.

Comment: This is actually not a reasonable question at all. Obviously, PAM isn't implemented yet, and the author is essentially looking for someone to do his work for him...

Comment: This algorithm has been included in a recent [pull request.](https://github.com/terkkila/scikit-learn/blob/kmedoids/sklearn/cluster/k_medoids_.py)

Answer (score 4):

### Start implementing!

We cannot answer a question like yours. You need to have a concrete question, not "where do I start".

If you don't really want to implement it yourself, you may need to choose a different tool, such as [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/) or R or Matlab that *do* already include PAM and maybe CLARA, too.

Answer (score 0):

pyclustering is your best bet:

https://github.com/annoviko/pyclustering

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyclustering/0.8.0

They've got PAM, and CLARANS (which may be the same as CLARA?).

Looks like the git repo has been around since February 2014.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried looking into Scikit learn? I have used been it quite a lot in ipython so can verify that it works well.

You can find all the documentation on their clustering algorithms here:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering

I don't exactly see something for k-medoid but maybe they have something there that can help.

Also, you can check out http://mlpy.sourceforge.net/. I have not used this package so cannot comment on how well it performs.

Comment: This seems to be not an answer to the OP's straightforward question. In none of the two links I could find any mentioning of k-medoid.

Comment: I agree that these links don't directly answer the question (as I pointed out) but I wanted to make the OP aware of the commercially available software for clustering in python. There are many methods available there and maybe one can be used.